# How to add to mongoDB(2.2.1) array from C#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having troubles understanding new mongoDB drivers for C#. In database, I have collection with array (comments: []). Now, I want to update(push) new comment to database, but with no success. I have tried various code, some are outdated etc. Last one that I'm trying to use is this:

```
var collection = mongoDbServer.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("post");
        var filter = Builders<PostInfo>.Filter.Eq(e => e._id, temp[0]);

        var update = Builders<PostInfo>.Update.Push<string>(e => e.Comments, temp[1]);
        await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

But there is error in "FindOneAndUpdateAsync". Am I doing something wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: what is the error in "FindOneAndUpdateAsync"?

Comment: The type arguments for method 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>, UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>, FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument, TProjection>, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using a collection of type `BsonDocument` but your filter and update definitions are of type `PostInfo`.

Does it work if you change your collection accessor to this?

```
var collection = mongoDbServer.GetCollection<PostInfo>("post");
```

Otherwise, your code for updating looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add a record not update it, so you should be using the `collection.InsertOneAsync(document)` method.

See this [link](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/07/insert-details-into-mongodb-using-c-and-.net.html) which walks thru an example.

Hope this helps..